# ChartJS generated random number at <canvas>

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

can someone help me with randomly generated 0 at the top of the ChartJS canvas.
Here is the js:

```
const chartConst= document.getElementById('canvasUnique').getContext('2d');
    const chartInit= new Chart(chartInit, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
            datasets: [{
                data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#CDF8FC',
                    '#FFEAD1',
                    '#CDF8FC',
                    '#FFEAD1',
                    '#CDF8FC',

                ],
                borderColor: [
                    '#CDF8FC',
                    '#FFEAD1',
                    '#CDF8FC',
                    '#FFEAD1',
                    '#CDF8FC',

                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                datalabels: {
                    anchor: 'end',
                    align: 'left'
                }
            }],
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        options: {
            plugins: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                }
            },
            responsive:true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    grid: {
                        display: false,
                        drawBorder: false,
                    }
                },
                x: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    grid: {
                        display: false,
                    }
                }
            },
        },
    });
```

It seems like there is some kind of random number at the top and I can not change it with HTML/CSS and I have checked if there is some kind of unclosed string at the js part.

[image]

Comment: is it always 0? if so it maybe to do with a label of sorts, i.e set `min: 0,` in `x:` to `min: 3,` or remove `indexAxis: 'y',` and see what happens

Comment: It is fixed had 6 data inputs on 5 datalabels :D Thanks guys